# Python Homework - file i/o - read file and turn into dictionary

Tags: python, file-io

I need to create a function that takes no arguments and reads back the dictionary that is in a previously-saved file. I must first determine if the file exists. If it does, I must read the contents of the file and return it as a dictionary. If not, return `[]`.

I'm fairly new to Python and I've been brain dead looking at this for a couple hours now. Any help would be much appreciated!

For example:

```
dave 12
brad 18
stacy 8
```

This would now be read as `{'dave': 12, 'brad': 18, 'stacy': 8}`.

So far I have this:

```
def readit():

    file1 = open('save.txt', 'r')
    data = []
    lines = file1.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        data.append(lines[i].split('\n'))
    return data
    file1.close()
```

Comment: `dict(x.split() for x in open("somefile.txt"))`

Comment: meh im assuming its cython in which case it is closed as soon as it moves out of scope ... also not much harm in leaving a file opened for reading ... but yeah ... you are right in other python implementations it may not GC as fast

Comment: Just taking the solution from SO is not such a good learning experience :-) In your solution, why did you work with a list [] when you want a dictionary {} as result?

Answer (score 4):

This'll do it:

```
import os.path

def readit():
    filename = 'save.txt'
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return {}
    with open(filename) as ifh:
        return dict(line.split() for line in ifh)
```

This first tests if the file exists; if it does not an empty dictionary is returned.

If there are spaces between the names, use `.rsplit(None, 1)`; this'll split on the last whitespace within the line only:

```
def readit():
    filename = 'save.txt'
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return {}
    with open('save.txt') as ifh:
        return dict(line.rsplit(None, 1) for line in ifh)
```

which will turn:

```
Martijn Pieters 42
user3014014 38
```

into

```
{'Martijn Pieters': '42', 'user3014014': '38'}
```

Note the `with` statement here also. This uses the file object as a context manager, meaning that as soon as the block exits (using `return`, due to an exception or simply because the block ends) then the file is automatically closed for you. Your `file1.close()` line on the other hand will never be executed as it is placed after the `return` statement.

The above, of course, gives us *strings* for values. Lets expand this to produce integer values instead:

```
def readit():
    filename = 'save.txt'
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return {}
    with open('save.txt') as ifh:
        return {key: int(value) for line in ifh for key, value in (line.rsplit(None, 1),)}
```

This produces:

```
{'Martijn Pieters': 42, 'user3014014': 38}
```

for my sample input.

Comment: hehe :P I posted almost the same in the comments :P

Comment: @mwil.me: Indeed, added.

Answer (score 1):

```
def readit():
  data = dict(x.split for x in open("save.txt"))
  return data
```

This should help you get it!